# spring boot controller mapping not registered with two separate modules

Tags: java, spring-boot, module, controller, mapping

I'm having two separate modules in my Spring boot application, and the application is packages in a wrapper and two jar file foe each module is included inside it. The problem is that the controllers in the module which doesn't include the main class don't get mapped.

The controller class :

```
@Controller
@Component
@RequestMapping(path = "/report/v2")
public class WebsiteController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/webinars", method = GET, produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public String getUsers() {
   // implementation

  }
}
```

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: What are the package names for the controllers?  Are those packages scanned?

Comment: the package name is 'io.sample.reportservice.controller'. not scanned explicitly. When I include a  '@ComponentScan({"io.sample.reportservice.controller" })' other controllers doesnt get mapped

Comment: Did you try to add all your controller's package in the _ComponentScan_ annotation ?